# Blender casting strange shadow based on where I'm looking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shadows

I'm currently experiencing an issue I can't find an answer to anywhere,
It seems like something is casting a shadow in my scene that any lights I place can't overwrite. And the area it covers changes based on where I look at it from. It also effects the lights making them cast light favoured to one side. Here are some example images, I have no clue what's going on.

PS. It's not some invisible object I tried booting up a new blender scene and just used a plane and the issue still showed up.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Edit: Someone asked if I was using a normal map, yes I am. everything was working perfectly for a while then idk when but this lighting just started happening out of nowhere.

[image: Image 4]

Comment: Are you using a Normal Map for your material?